# Python: Get attribute from a list of objects of the same type in the most efficient way

Tags: python, list, class

I was wondering which is the best way to obtain an attribute from a list of objects of the same type. Is there a more efficient solution than a for loop? I tried with getattr but is not working with lists.

Just to make it clear. Let's say I've defined a class Foo with attribute `Bar`

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, Bar):
        self.bar = Bar

A = Foo(5)
B = Foo(6)
C = [A,B]
```

Can I do something to obtain the attribute `Bar` at the same time for the whole list so that the final result would be a list with values [5,6] ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Your example is missing colons on the first two lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a list-comp:

```
C = [obj.Bar for obj in (A, B)]
```

Or alternatively:

```
from operator import attrgetter
C = map(attrgetter('Bar'), (A, B))
```

Note: It's not strictly "*at the same time*" but looping over the objects one-by-one is as good as it gets. Also note, the objects don't even need to be of the same type - they just need to have an attribute `Bar`. You can use `getattr`  to return default values if the attribute doesn't exist:

```
C = [getattr(obj, 'Bar', None) for obj in (A, B)]
```

Or, if you wanted to discard items that don't have that attribute instead of a default value:

```
C = [obj.Bar for obj in (A, B) if hasattr(obj, 'Bar')]
```

Comment: Why attrgetter and not getattr? (on phone)

Comment: @JonClements how about `from functools import partial; C = map(partial(getattr, name='Bar'), (A, B))`? (Of course, `attrgetter()` is still the more flexible choice due to its ability to retrieve multiple attributes at once (`attrgetter('bar', 'foo')(A)` -> `(A.bar, A.foo)`))

Comment: @JAB it's an alternative... Or another (horrible) alternative is `from operator import methodcaller; C = map(methodcaller('__getattribute__', 'Bar'), (A, B))`

Answer (score 0):

```
C = [getattr(obj, 'Bar') for obj in [A, B]]
```

You could even use:

```
>>> for nam in dir():
...     obj = eval(nam)
...     if isinstance(obj, Foo):
...        C.append(getattr(obj, 'Bar'))
...
>>> C
[5, 6]
```